# How to Control Sequence Length in "load_summarize_chain" with "map_reduce" from langchain? - Exceeding Maximum Token Indices Error

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

Could you please explain the way to control "sequence length" when we use `map_reduce` with `load_summarize_chain` from `langchain`?

```
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
        chunk_size=600,
        chunk_overlap=0,
        length_function=len,
)
docs = splitter.create_documents([text])

summary_chain = load_summarize_chain(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="map_reduce",
        map_prompt="some map prompt",
        combine_prompt="some combine prompt",
)
summary_chain.run(docs)
```

This is the code returns an error.

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (4084 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors.
```

My guess is that this occurs when the mapper generates outputs that are too long. Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

More technical answer, this is the working code with the output sample. Also make sure you have all settings on your machine like environment variables etc. setup on your machine

```
        from langchain.chains.mapreduce import MapReduceChain
        from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
        from langchain.chains import ReduceDocumentsChain, MapReduceDocumentsChain

        from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
        from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
        from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
        from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
        from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
        from langchain.chains.combine_documents.stuff import StuffDocumentsChain

        loader = WebBaseLoader("https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/")
        docs = loader.load()

        llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k")
        chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")

        chain.run(docs)

        llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)

        # Map
        map_template = """The following is a set of documents
        {docs}
        Based on this list of docs, please identify the main themes 
        Helpful Answer:"""
        map_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(map_template)
        map_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=map_prompt)

        # Reduce
        reduce_template = """The following is set of summaries:
        {doc_summaries}
        Take these and distill it into a final, consolidated summary of the main themes. 
        Helpful Answer:"""
        reduce_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(reduce_template)

        # Run chain
        reduce_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=reduce_prompt)

        # Takes a list of documents, combines them into a single string, and passes this to an LLMChain
        combine_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
            llm_chain=reduce_chain, document_variable_name="doc_summaries"
        )

        # Combines and iteravely reduces the mapped documents
        reduce_documents_chain = ReduceDocumentsChain(
            # This is final chain that is called.
            combine_documents_chain=combine_documents_chain,
            # If documents exceed context for `StuffDocumentsChain`
            collapse_documents_chain=combine_documents_chain,
            # The maximum number of tokens to group documents into.
            token_max=4000,
        )


        # Combining documents by mapping a chain over them, then combining results
        map_reduce_chain = MapReduceDocumentsChain(
            # Map chain
            llm_chain=map_chain,
            # Reduce chain
            reduce_documents_chain=reduce_documents_chain,
            # The variable name in the llm_chain to put the documents in
            document_variable_name="docs",
            # Return the results of the map steps in the output
            return_intermediate_steps=False,
        )

        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter.from_tiktoken_encoder(
            chunk_size=1024, chunk_overlap=0
        )
        split_docs = text_splitter.split_documents(docs)

        print(map_reduce_chain.run(split_docs))
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bot answer

Comment: added more technical details.